# Postgis docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, postgis

как добавить postgis к postgresql?

пытаюсь добавить расгирение postgis в postgresql, но пишет

```
ERROR:  extension "postgis" is not available
DETAIL:  Could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/15/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory.
HINT:  The extension must first be installed on the system where PostgreSQL is running.
```

мой docker-compose

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  fl.api:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
      # Only will build development stage from our dockerfile
      target: development
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    env_file:
      - .env
      # Run a command against the development stage of the image
    command: npm run start:dev
    ports:
      - 6545:6545
    networks:
      - nesjs-network
  redis:
    image: 'redis:alpine'
    ports:
      - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
    volumes:
      - fl-redis:/data
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "redis-cli", "ping" ]
      retries: 3
      timeout: 5s
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    networks:
      - nesjs-network
    volumes:
      - fl-postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - nesjs-network
networks:
  nesjs-network:
volumes:
  fl-redis:
    driver: local
  fl-postgres:
    driver: local
```

Comment: Ну вроде бы вменяемо написано: *Could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/15/extension/postgis.control": **No such file or directory.*** Трудно добавить то, чего нет...

Comment: не могу понять как добавить в docker-compose postgis

Comment: Это вообще-то сайт не только вопросов, но и ответов... неужели трудно воспользоваться поиском? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65293118/10138734 Или сразу к оригиналу: https://registry.hub.docker.com/r/postgis/postgis/

Comment: добавил в dockerfile но что-то ничего не поменялось, не видит postgis